# Form field in django should not be none and Cannot read property 'value' error in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-maps, django-forms

I am obtaining the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null in javascript-

I have this form in django.

```
class userRequest(forms.Form):

    lat_Origin = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={"id":"lat_Origin"}),required=False,initial=181)
    lon_Origin = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={"id":"lon_Origin"}),required=False,initial=181)
    lat_Dest = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={"id":"lat_Dest"}),required=False,initial=181)
    lon_Dest = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={"id":"lon_Dest"}),required=False,initial=181)

    origin_address=forms.CharField(max_length=200,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"data_aux data","id":"origin_address"}))
    destination_address=forms.CharField(max_length=200,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"data_aux data","id":"destination_address"}))
```

When I print form.cleaned_data:

```
{'lat_Origin': None, 'lon_Origin': None, 'lat_Dest': None, 'lon_Dest': None, 'origin_address': 'Calle San Amaro, 1A, 09001 Burgos, España', 
'destination_address': "Calle de O'Donnell, Madrid, España", 'date': datetime.date(2021, 6, 12), 'maxPrice': None, 'OrderType': 'NONE', 'OrderBy': 'PRICE'}
```

I don't know why lat_Origin, lon_Origin, lat_Dest, lon_Dest are none.

I am using JS google maps api. I want to save coordinates values into lat_Origin, lon_Origin, lat_Dest, lon_Dest.

I obtain latitude and longitude data correctly using google maps geocoder (I have printed them with console.log) but I don`t know why they are finally none.

The view (start_coordinates and end_coordinates are none:

```
def home(request):

    blablaTrips={}
    skyscannerTrips={}
    trips_busTrain={}


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userRequest(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            id_delete=set()
            for trip in Trip.objects.all():
                if (hasattr(trip,"busOrTrainTrip")==False):
                    id_delete.add(trip.id)

            Trip.objects.all().filter(id__in=id_delete).delete() #Borro los viajes en avión y en blablacar

            date=form.cleaned_data['date']
            start_date_local=dt(date.year,date.month,date.day)
    
            start_coordinates=str(form.cleaned_data['lat_Origin'])+','+str(form.cleaned_data['lon_Origin'])
            end_coordinates=str(form.cleaned_data['lat_Dest'])+','+str(form.cleaned_data['lon_Dest'])

            print(form.cleaned_data)
```

The function in JS:

```
function get_address_withLocation(lat, lng, map, is_origin) {
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    const latlng = {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
    };
    geocoder.geocode({ location: latlng }, (results, status) => {
        if (status === "OK") {
            if (results[0]) {
                map.setZoom(7);
                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                });
                contentString =
                    '<div id="content-map">' +
                    '<p>' + results[0].formatted_address + '</p>' +
                    "</div>";
                infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);


                window.alert(is_origin);
                if (is_origin) {
                    document.getElementById('origin_address').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                    console.log(lat);
                    console.log(lng);
                    document.getElementById('lat_Origin').value = lat;
                    document.getElementById('lon_Origin').value = lng;
                    remove_mapMarkers('origin_address', marker)


                } else {
                    console.log(lat);
                    console.log(lng);
                    document.getElementById('destination_address').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                    document.getElementById('lat_Dest').value = lat;
                    document.getElementById('lon_Dest').value = lng;
                    remove_mapMarkers('destination_address', marker);


                }



            } else {
                window.alert("No results found");
            }

        } else {
            window.alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: Are you sure the id for the field is like `lat_Origin` and not `id_lat_Origin` (Check the rendered HTML using your browsers developer tools)? Please show your view, template and if you submit the form via JavaScript show that too.

Comment: Ok, I am goint to add more information